# Database First MVC App giving user instance error on hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-database-first

I have developed a web app in MVC 5 with the Database First approach.
When hosting the app I get an error "Generating user instances in SQL Server is disabled. Use sp_configure 'user instances enabled' to generate user instances."

The thing is that this only happens when I host the application on the server. When ran locally there are no errors. I am not sure what is causing this error as I am using an online database connection,not local mdf file. From what research I've done on this error I can only find examples where people have used a local database.

Below is the web.config connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings> 

<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=***.***.***.**,1434;Initial Catalog=tsp13amp_tsp136;User Id=******;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
<add name="TSPEntities" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.TSPEntities.csdl|res://*/Models.TSPEntities.ssdl|res://*/Models.TSPEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=***.***.***.**,1434;Initial Catalog=tsp13amp_tsp136;User Id=******;Password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" />
```

And the stacktrace as I can't seem to make head or tails of it:

```
 [SqlException (0x80131904): Generating user instances in SQL Server is disabled. Use sp_configure 'user instances enabled' to generate user instances.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6568558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +717
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4515
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +84
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +368
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6597311
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6597891
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +942
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +816
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +61
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +953
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6605639
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +98

[HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database.]
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.GetSqlConnection(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString) +4572298
   System.Web.Management.SqlServices.SetupApplicationServices(String server, String user, String password, Boolean trusted, String connectionString, String database, String dbFileName, SqlFeatures features, Boolean install) +229
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.CreateMdfFile(String fullFileName, String dataDir, String connectionString) +908
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It's is possible this feature is disabled on the server, use following script on the database server to activate it:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'user instances enabled', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```